# Find value for 3-dimensional function f such that f is continuous at (0,0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f$ be a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3\setminus M \to \mathbb{R}$ where $M:= \{(x,y,z)^t \in \mathbb{R}^3\; |\; x = y = 0,\; z\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and
$$f(x,y,z) = \frac{xz^2+y^3}{x^2+y^2}.$$
Examine if there's a possible value $m = f(0,0,0)$ such that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0,0)^t$.

I suspect for $m:=0$ that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0,0)^t$. However I'm failing to prove it.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $(x,y,z)^t \in \mathbb{R}^3\setminus M$:
$$|f(x,y,z)| = \frac{|xz^2 + y^3|}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{|x||z|^2+|y|^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

How do I proceed from here? Advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus M$ defined as  $a_n = (\tfrac{1}{n^3}, 0, \tfrac{1}{n})$.

What is $\lim_{n\to\inf} f(a_n)$?

Comment: The sequence $a_n$ isn't in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus M$ since, $y = 0$, so I can't use that

Comment: But $x \not= 0$. The constrain is $x=y=0$, not $xy=0$.

Comment: Am I missing something here? $M = \{(0,0,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3\; | \; z \in \mathbb{R}\}$ so $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus M$ would mean that $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$.

Comment: @Shuster: Why would $(1,0,z)$ fit the profile of $(0,0,z)$ for instance?

Comment: My bad. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the limits where $y\equiv0$ along the path $z=a\sqrt{x}$ where $x>0$. Then we have
$$
f(x,0,a\sqrt{x})=\frac{xz^2+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{ax^2}{x^2}=a
$$
This shows how this must be impossible, since you can find a path to convergence towards any value $a$ on the number line. This can also be seen directly from the following plot of $g(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2}$ which is essentially $g(x,y)=f(x,0,y)$:

[image]

Comment: See my comment under @mwt's answer.

Comment: @Shuster: That does not appear to be the definition of $M$. To be in $M$ we should have both $x=0$ and $y=0$ which is not the case in either answer. This makes sense, since $x=y=0$ seems to be the problem in the first place.

Comment: see comments under @mwt's answer.